# php howto unset static var

Tags: php

i have a function like this. i want reset the $output var first call.

```
function create_tree($tree_array, $reset = TRUE, $ul_class = FALSE) {

    if($reset) unset($output); // NOT WORK!!!

    static $output = '';

    $class = '';
    if ($ul_class) {
        $class = ' class="' . $ul_class . '"';
    }
    $output .= '<ul' . $class . '>' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($tree_array as $v) {

        $output .= '<li><a href="'  . site_url_i18n($v['link']) . '">' . $v['name'] . '</a>' . PHP_EOL;;

        if (isset($v['children'])) {
            create_tree($v['children'], false);
        }

        $output .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $output .= '</ul>' . PHP_EOL;

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? Should it be initialized with the empty string again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$output` doesn't magically exist at that point in the function; it magically retains its value when the declaration is seen again.

```
if ($reset)
   $output = '';
```

Comment: I would also suggest to put the `static` statement in the first place: `static $output = ''; if ($reset) $output = '';` Its usually more readable.